# Access tab bar badge from any class - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, nsobject

I have a tab bar view controller based application. I have 3 main view controllers in the app and one custom class (called "DataManager") of type `NSObject`.

Since my DataManager class handles all the data, I would like to just update the tab bar badge from that class (instead of the view controllers).

However, I am unable to access the tab bar view controller from my custom class. Is there a way that this can be done?

Here is my code (DataManger - header):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DataManager : NSObject <UITabBarControllerDelegate> {

}

// Trolley data methods.
-(NSMutableArray *)get_trolley_data;
-(void)update_trolley:(NSMutableArray *)data;
-(int)get_trolley_size;

// Data check methods.
-(NSString *)text_check:(NSString *)data :(int)type;

// Tab bar methods.
-(void)update_badge;

@end
```

And here is the implementation code:

```
#import "DataManager.h"

@implementation DataManager

/*

other methods.......

*/

/// TAB BAR METHODS ///

-(void)update_badge {

    // Get the trolley size.
    int num = [self get_trolley_size];

    // Set the tab bar number badge.
    UITabBarItem *tab_bar = [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem];

    // Show the badge if the count is
    // greater than 0 otherwise hide it.

    if (num > 0) {
        [tab_bar setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]];
    }

    else {
        [tab_bar setBadgeValue:nil];
    }

    return;
}

@end
```

I get the following error:

> Property 'tabBarController' not found on object of type 'DataManager
>   *'.

So is there a way that I can access the tab bar controller from my custom class? If I try to update the tab bar badge from my view controllers, then I will end up having the copy the above method multiple times which is just stupid.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
-(void)update_badge {

    // Get the trolley size.
    int num = [self get_trolley_size];

    // Get RootViewController That is surely your tabbarcontroller
    UITabBarController *tabBarController =(UITabBarController*)[[(YourAppDelegate*)
                                   [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];

    // Set the tab bar number badge.
    UITabBarItem *tab_bar = [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem];

    // Show the badge if the count is
    // greater than 0 otherwise hide it.

    if (num > 0) {
        [tab_bar setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]];
    }

    else {
        [tab_bar setBadgeValue:nil];
    }

    return;
}
```

**Note:** must replace `YourAppDelegate` with your actual `AppDelegate` class.

Comment: This works perfectly, just had to ```#import "AppDelegate.h"``` and it worked like a charm! Thank you :)